# Binding ng-click to ng-repeat on a dynamic array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

#### Context

I have an array `hand`. I'm using `ng-repeat="card in hand"` to iterate through the cards. I have `ng-click="select(card)"` to do something with said card.

This works fine when using the initial values of `hand`, but once I start adding cards to the `hand` array, `ng-click` no longer fires.

#### Question

How can I get `ng-click` to fire in an `ng-repeat` on a dynamic array?

#### Code (simplified)

card.html:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{data.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{data.description}}</p>
    <button ng-click="select(data)">Select</button>
</div>
```

hand.html

```
<card ng-repeat="card in hand" data="card"></card>
```

card.js:

```
app.directive('card', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'card.html',
        controller: 'HandCtrl'
    };
});
```

hand.js:

```
app.directive('hand', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'hand.html',
        controller: 'HandCtrl'
    };
});
```

handCtrl.js:

```
app.controller('HandCtrl', ['$scope', 'getHand', function($scope, getHand) {
    getHand.then(function(hand) {
        $scope.hand = hand;
        $scope.select = function(card) {
            card.selected = true;
            $scope.hand.splice(card.position, 1);
        };
    });
}]);
```

elsewhere in the code...

```
app.controller('DeckCtrl', ['$scope', 'getDeck', 'getHand', function($scope, getDeck, getHand) {
    getDeck.then(function(deck) {
        $scope.deck = deck;
        getHand.then(function(hand) {
            $scope.hand = hand;
            $scope.drawCard = function() {
                var card = deck.splice(0, 1)[0];
                // ng-repeat shows this new card, but ng-click doesn't trigger
                $scope.hand.push(card);
            };
        });
    });
}]);
```

which is triggered by

```
<button ng-click="drawCard">Draw</button>
```

Comment: where is the code which adds the new card. Show us the full code for that.

Comment: @Shyju added the code.

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid object in `card` before pushing it to the array ?

Comment: Yes--`ng-repeat` shows the new card (title, description, etc). It's just that clicking on the "Select" button doesn't trigger the `ng-click` on the new cards only.

Comment: Your problem is that you do `$scope.hand.splice(card.position, 1);` but you never update the other cards card.position ;)

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Thanks. Please vote-close this question. Brain fart on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

switch your ng-repeat to `ng-repeat="(index, card) in hand"` and pass the index to your function like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{data.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{data.description}}</p>
    <button ng-click="select(index)">Select</button>
</div>
```

and update your javascript code to manipulate the `hand` array directly. Should work fine.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. I'm pretty sure I _am_ manipulating the `hand` array directly by modifying `$scope.hand`. Thanks for the trick with passing through the index though--that's helpful in other ways :)